# Organise a springboot project from scratch

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm just starting to learn java springboot and I want to start a project from scratch (means I don't want the IDE to generate the needed files and config for me).

So far I know springboot:

- read the pom.xml file from the root
- check the src/main/java folder for any application

is there any advice how I can organize my project, if I want to adopt a MVC approach?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`pom.xml` only is required for Maven projects, not mandated by Spring. You could use Gradle, SBT, or any other JVM dependency manager, or you could manage the classpath yourself with custom Jars.

It is Maven, Gradle, etc that dictate the `src/main/java` default directory structure, not the IDE or Spring.

You don't necessarily need the IDE to do it, but you *should* use [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/) as this will keep all your dependencies consistent and give you the recommended project structure.
Otherwise, you need to ensure that you download all necessary dependencies yourself, then create your main class/method that invokes the Spring Application runner, but that could be in any folder structure, and you could use `javac` to compile it.

Comment: ah ok I see. Thanks for the answer. that means depending on which repository manager i choose (maven or gradle) I have to respect a specific folder structure. right? 
I already used the spring initializer and I got a lot of folder + windows files generated. That's why I decided to try from scratch, for me to have a deep understanding of the role of each file or the folder structure. I will keep digging. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "lot". I just created a Maven-based project with some dependencies that I would use for a webapp, and I get one `src` folder with source code and unit tests. Anything within that is a standard structure for a Maven app. Nested folders repersent Java application packaging, which you can learn without Spring. The properties file in `src/main/resources` used for Spring. Then there is only one `mvnw.cmd` flie that is used for Windows.

Comment: You're basically right.

Comment: I have the following structure 
+ src (main [java { package hierachy } , ressources { application.properties }], test)
+ .mvn
+ HELP.md
+ mvnw
+ mvnw.cmd
+ pom.xml
+ .gitignore

I start to get why I need all the files. but if i have a package like com.myproject and want to organize my code in com.myproject.model, com.myproject.view, com.myproject.controller and well having additionally the rest services, target, webapp etc ...  to be organized, it can get messy with the folder hierachy. That's why I was wondering if someone can have an advice for me

Comment: That's not messy, and still not related to Spring. Large java applications have hundreds of different packages